# Checking for specific numbers in a string using Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This must be an easy one, but I am trying to detect if the integers 28, 81, 379 or 380 exist in a string.

I was using this pattern:

```
    pattern = /28|81|379|380/
```

But it also returns true for 381.  So I need a modifier to make sure it is only looking for 81 specifically, and not 81 within a longer number.  I know about the ^ and $ modifiers to check for the start and end, but I can't seem to figure out how to work those in to a pattern that is using the | symbol to check alternatives.

Regex is not my strength - hope you can help! - Dan

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like:

```
/\b(?:28|81|379|380)\b/
```

With `\b` matching at a "word barrier", so these numbers will not match if they are part of a word/other numbers.

If you want to match 28 in `foo28` (part of a "word") then you can use:

```
/(?:^|\D)(?:28|81|379|380)(?:\D|$)/
```

`\D` matches a not-number character.

Comment: Thanks QTax!  What does the ?: do?

Comment: @Dan Baylis that signifies a non-capturing group (meaning the group will not be available as a backreference)

Answer (score 2):

`\b` signifies a word boundary.  You might use it as such:

```
/\b28\b|\b81\b|\b379\b|\b380\b/
```

Or as such:

```
/\b(28|81|379|380)\b/
```

Comment: @Dan Baylis Good to hear.  If you aren't using the value, it might be worth it to make it a non-capturing group as in Qtax's example.